# My ubuntu system suddenly got somehow reset

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, mount, reset, tls

One day when I boot up on ubuntu after entering the password (I only have one user) suddenly the display went off for a sec and then everything was like reset to a fresh install! All new sudo commands I have done beforehand was when I was installing WireShark from source, which I guess was 2 days before the incident.

So it was reset, my background, my dock and my favorites. But I had my installed apps and themes for the top bar and windows and all, they were just disabled. So I thought it was all this but then I saw the unsolved problems. The one second blank screen shows up everytime I login to my user. The gsconnect keeps giving me TLS error, after many reinstalls through both the gnome extensions and git

```
TLS support is not available
Gio.TlsCertificate.new_for_paths@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/__init__.js:352:31
_initCertificate@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/backends/lan.js:177:48
start@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/backends/lan.js:440:18
_loadBackends@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/manager.js:251:25
start@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/manager.js:454:14
vfunc_startup@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/daemon.js:258:22
vfunc_handle_local_options@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/daemon.js:664:18
@/home/adjective/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io/service/daemon.js:727:17
```

Also my laptop ports do not mount automatically. When I connect my external hard drive or my phone, it does not appear in the files window and the dmesg command gives me this:

```
usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=10b8, bcdDevice=10.07 
usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 2-1: Product: Elements 10B8
usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 5758373145423343454B3230
usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 10B8    1007 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
......ready
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953458176 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
sdc: sdc1
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=26667 end=26668) time 280 us, min 1064, max 1079, scanline start 1049, end 1087
```

I can mount it through commandline though but I rather like it fixed.

It's a long written problem and I really appreciate the time you put in reading this. Thanks in advance.